# On Android Browser always getting image width 10810 with jQuery and FileReader

Tags: android, jquery, image, width, filereader

This is weird. I tried to pick up an image to preview it in a div using the HTML5 FileReader.readAsDataURL() function and a inline-image. This works fine on most browsers incl. iPhone's Safari.
But if I'm using the standard Android browser on a Samsung Nexus AND pick a photo which is stored on the phone I alwas get a width of 10810px and a height of 4286px regardless of which size the source image has, when I use a picture directly by taking a new photo it works. I get the correct sizes. :@ I tried naturalWitdh, width, using jQUery and native javascript. All with same results

```
 $('#file-input').change(function () {
    if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {
        var files = this.files ? this.files : this.currentTarget.files;
        if (files && files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#picture')
                .attr('src', e.target.result).attr('style', '')
                .load(function () {
                    console.log('w:' + $(this).width());
                });
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
        }
    } else {
        alert('an error message');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried hooking chrome up to your computer's chrome to see if the image and or divs are doing anything funky?

Comment: yes, they do it really funky. it works on the same device using a chrome browser, too

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found a solution for android (browser) 4.0 and up.

I found that it works correctly if you use the `createObjectURL` function to do something like the following:

```
function getImgSize(input) {

    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var apiURL = (window.createObjectURL && window) 
                        || (window.URL && URL.revokeObjectURL && URL) 
                        || (window.webkitURL && webkitURL);

        var url = apiURL.createObjectURL(input.files[0]);

        $('#testImg').attr('src', url);
    }
}

$('#testImg').on('load',function(){
                alert($(this).width()+'*'+$(this).height());
            });

$("input").change(function(){
    getImgSize(this);
});
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/bravoman/qm2C5/5/ for a full example and use http://jsfiddle.net/bravoman/qm2C5/5/embedded/result/ to test it on your device/emulator.